# Angular tracked hashKey not printing

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning angular from a book but I've reached an example that doesn't seem to be working.  I have this:

```
<div ng-repeat="note in ctrl.notes track by note.id">
    {{note.$$hashKey}}
    <span class="label"> {{note.label}}</span>
    <span class="author" ng-bind="note.done"></span>
</div>
```

and in the controller:

```
        this.notes = [
            {
                id: 1,
                label: 'Changed Note',
                done: false,
                someRandom: 4242
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                label: 'Second Note',
                done: false
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                label: 'Finished Third Note',
                done: true
            }
        ];
```

The problem is that without track by note.id it prints from 3, but while adding track by note.id, it is supposed to print by the ids... but it doesn't print anything, it is blank and there are no errors in the console. Is this the normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

**Pen: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/EjPeML**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. `$$hashkey` is angular's way of remembering which object relates to which html elements.

Using "track by note.id" tells angular "Here, use this instead. I'm providing a collection of `notes`, and every `note` will have an `id` property and it will be unique." When you use a tracking expression angular has no need for the `$$hashkey` so it doesn't generate one. Your book is probably either a mis-print or it's out of date.

Comment: I understand it substitutes the original counter with the note.id, but why does it not print the id either? what is the use for this track by whatever, then?

Comment: It doesn't print the id because your html is looking for $$hashkey. If you want to print out the id then use this: {{note.id}}

Comment: but if wanted to print the id I could write {{note.id}} from the begining without using the $$hashkey, so why is the "track by" there?

Comment: The use of "track by whatever" allows you to use ng-repeat without modifying your original objects; the performance is slightly better when it's used; you can also swap out an object with a different instance of that object (but with the same id) and angular will treat them as the same, and not redraw the DOM. It's a bit more involved than I can explain in this comment.

Your example code would work just fine with or without "track by". It's more of a good practice for an optimization that should be done whenever possible. The intention might be clearer if I knew the objective of that tutorial

Comment: This is the book and the script: https://github.com/shyamseshadri/angularjs-up-and-running/blob/master/chapter2/ng-repeat-track-by-id.html

Comment: It shows 2 examples, both with and without "track by". They're showing you the differences between each way. Try adding a text input field, type into it, then press the "Change notes" button, then maybe the difference will be clearer: `<div ng-repeat="note in ctrl.notes track by note.id">
    {{note.$$hashKey}}
    <span class="label"> {{note.label}}</span>
    <span class="author" ng-bind="note.done"></span>
    <input type="text"></input>
</div>`

Comment: I'm expecting that when you press the button the text you type into the text field will be lost unless you use "track by" because the DOM elements are replaced by new ones.

Comment: I don't understand the last you said

Comment: Don't worry about it. Just know that they are different. When you can use "track by" then do, and whenever it's not possible angular will do its best by adding $$hashKey.